# R: Text xyz to multiple raster

Tags: r, data-conversion, r-raster, rasterizing

I have a comma delimited text files with the header names

```
lat,long,z1,z2,z3,z4,z5
```

These columns contain the lat, long and multiple height values(z1, z2,z3, z4). The lat and long data is spaced at an equal interval of 5 meters.

What is the most efficient way to convert the data into individual rasters or an R  raster stack each having the z values,  given the projection information is UTM, zone 18.

The sample data can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sjr02xodtuory8/sample_data.csv?dl=0).

Comment: have you look into the raster package?

Comment: or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627344/how-to-create-a-raster-from-a-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
x <- data.frame(lon=1:11, lat=5:15, z1=runif(11), z2=11:1)
library(raster)
b <- rasterFromXYZ(x)

#> b
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 11, 11, 121, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0.5, 11.5, 4.5, 15.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA 
#data source : in memory
#names       :         z1,         z2 
#min values  : 0.08495835, 1.00000000
```

Comment: Thank you RobertH, I love raster package. I was not aware of "rasterFromXYZ" function.