# Convert three vectors (lat, lon, value) to raster object in R

Tags: r, raster

I have three numeric vectors which describes:

- lat - lattitude
- long - longitute
- value - value for specified point (for point in specific location defined by pai lat and long)

How can I create from them a raster object?
I've tried to use cbind to combine them:

```
# I prefer pacman::p_load(raster) to load package
library('raster')

# Sample very small subset of data:
lat <- c(84.6564178466797, 84.6564178466797, 83.3252105712891, 82.2175979614258, 
80.3753433227539, 78.830451965332, 83.3252105712891)
long <- c(-145.316390991211, -70.6275939941406, -135.606842041016, -113.573654174805, 
-102.370330810547, -104.610992431641, -79.5902481079102)
value <- c(0.379887759685516, 0.297680675983429, 0.259096682071686, 0.195639669895172, 
0.259653329849243, 0.278579145669937, 0.333345)

myMatrix <- cbind(lat,long,value)

#this raster seems to be *incorrect*, because it shows: values: -145.3164, 84.65642  (min, max)
raster(myMatrix)

#Following causes an error (x cell sizes are not regular):
rasterFromXYZ(myMatrix)
```

but created object stores incorrect values.

Will I need to create a matrix first as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513480/convert-matrix-to-raster-in-r) topic?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627344/how-to-create-a-raster-from-a-data-frame-in-r) could help

Comment: @akrun Thank you, but intervals between my coordinates are not equal. I receive an error message when I try your suggested solution: 

gridded(spg) <- TRUE
suggested tolerance minimum: 0.944784 
Błąd w poleceniu 'points2grid(points, tolerance, round)':
  dimension 1 : coordinate intervals are not constant

should I process my data firstly (guess using interpolation method)

Comment: There's exactly the same issue when calling rasterFromXYZ:

rasterFromXYZ(cbind(lat,long,value))
Błąd w poleceniu 'rasterFromXYZ(cbind(lat, long, moisture))':
  x cell sizes are not regular